# Display white bar at the bottom when upgrade to new version of phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, mobile

I have recently upgraded my mobile android app from Cordova cli 4.2 & Cordova 4.0 to a new version of Cordova cli 5.3.9 and Cordova 4.1.1

I have used Android Sumsung s6 (v5.0) device demonstrate the issue.

When the app starts it displays a white bar at the bottom of the screen like  a status bar. See image attached.[attached Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nehkf.png)

Sometimes I don't get the white bar displayed. I am not sure if there is a bug in the  new version of Cordova cli 5.3.9 and Cordova 4.1.1

I am using jquery mobile framework version 1.4.5
MainActivity.java

index.html 
    `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    new SimpleEula(this).show();
    }`

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
```

I am not sure if there is a Cordova configuration i need to change or something in the androidManifest.xmlI think the issue is with Cordova webview display.
Happy to investigate any suggestions.

Comment: I had same issue.. I solved using this css, try this may be useful for you   .ui-mobile, .ui-mobile body{ min-height:100% !important;
 height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: modified my css. Made no difference. The white bar still appears as the bottom. What I have noticed is  with the new version of phonegap, when  you select some text on the app, the white bar moves to the top  but with options of share, copy etc.  When you press X to exit the white option bar, the app looks fine until i restart the app and get the white bar at the bottom of the app again.

Comment: it happens only in S6 or all phones..?

Comment: can you share your code ?